# При запуске пустого геттера всё равно выводится результат. Откуда?

Tags: c++, ооп, get

При запуске пустого геттера всё равно выводится результат. Откуда?

Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    void ChangeFirstName(int year, const string &first_name) {
        year_to_name.emplace_back(year, make_pair(first_name, ""));
    }

    void ChangeLastName(int year, const string &last_name) {
        year_to_name.emplace_back(year, make_pair("", last_name));
    }

    string GetFullName(int year) {
    }

private:
    vector<pair<int, pair<string, string>>> year_to_name;
};

int main() {
    Person person;

    person.ChangeFirstName(1965, "Polina");
    person.ChangeLastName(1967, "Sergeeva");
    for (int year : {1900, 1965, 1990}) {
        cout << person.GetFullName(year) << endl;
    }

    person.ChangeFirstName(1970, "Appolinaria");
    for (int year : {1969, 1970}) {
        cout << person.GetFullName(year) << endl;
    }

    person.ChangeLastName(1968, "Volkova");
    for (int year : {1969, 1970}) {
        cout << person.GetFullName(year) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод

```
Sergeeva
Sergeeva
Sergeeva
Appolinaria
Appolinaria
Volkova
Volkova
```

Comment: А как оно у вас вообще скомпилировалось?... Без `return` в `GetFullName`?  А если и скомпилировать как непритязательное к стандарту расширение GCC - все равно в пролете... https://ideone.com/2rJU55 Как вам удалось получить то, что удалось?

Comment: Вангую: вы забиваете на то, что прога не компилится и просто запускаете бинарник, который был скомпилен до ломающих компиляцию изменений

Comment: Скомпилил чере g++ выдало только warning

Comment: g++ -o test --std=c++17 test.cpp

Comment: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   21 |     }
      |     ^

Comment: @AlexEsn может прочтете больше одной строки вывода?

Comment: test.cpp: In member function ‘std::string Person::GetFullName(int)’:
test.cpp:21:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   21 |     }
      |     ^

Comment: @AlexEsn указывайте имя через @, тогда тот, к кому вы обращаетесь получит уведомление. А говорил я о том, что тот код, который вы привели не компилируется. Да, сейчас вы это исправили, но это было до того, как вы написали этот коммент

Comment: В команде компилятору добавьте `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wold-style-cast -Wshadow -Wpedantic -Werror`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Да, понял. Там почему-то #include <iostream> слетела сначала. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартом C++ отсутствие return в любой функции (кроме `main`) описано как неопределенное поведерние.

Это означает, что программа может вести себя произвольным образом - упасть, отформатировать диск, либо даже выдать что-то осмысленное.

Программы, содержащие неопределенное поведение, к работе не годятся и должны быть исправлены.